# Handling missing dates and adding NA values in corresponding parameters

Tags: r, shiny

I am working on a Shiny app to analyze climate data. The data is structured with columns y, m, d, p1, p2, and p3. However, some dates are missing, and I want to add them to the dataset with corresponding NA values in the parameters p1, p2, and p3.

Here's an example of the data format:

```
y   m   d   p1  p2  p3
2023 1   1   0   40  42
2023 1   2   0   40  25
2023 1   3   2   56  23
2023 1   6   5   65  65
2023 1   7   1   2   5
2023 1   10  5   6   2
```

I have written a function, fill_missing_dates, which takes the data as input and should return a dataframe with all the dates from the minimum to the maximum date in the dataset, with NA values filled in for missing dates.

Here's the code for the Shiny app and the fill_missing_dates function:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)

# Define the UI
ui <- fluidPage(theme = shinytheme("sandstone"),
                titlePanel("Outil d'évaluation des données climatiques"),
                sidebarLayout(
                  sidebarPanel(
                    h3("Chargement des données"),
                    fileInput("simul", "Sélectionnez le fichier pour les réanalyses ou les simulations:"),
                    fileInput("obs", "Sélectionnez le fichier pour l'observation:"),
                    actionButton("submitBtn", "Soumettre")
                  ),
                  mainPanel(
                    h4("Controle de qualité des donnee"),
                    fluidRow(
                      column(width = 6, tableOutput("obsout")),
                      column(width = 6, tableOutput("simulout"))
                    )
                  )
                )
)

# Define the server
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  fill_missing_dates <- function(data) {
    # Convert year, month, and day columns to Date object
    cc <- as.Date(paste(data$V1, data$V2, data$V3, sep = "-"))
    new_data <- data.frame(Date = cc, RR = data$V4, Tmax = data$V5, Tmin = data$V6)
    # Step 1: Create a full date vector
    v1_dates <- cc
    min_date <- min(v1_dates)
    max_date <- max(v1_dates)
    full_date_vector <- seq(from = min_date, to = max_date, by = "day")
    
    # Step 2: Find the missing dates
    missing_dates <- full_date_vector[!(full_date_vector %in% v1_dates)]
    
    # Step 3: Replace corresponding values with NA for missing dates
    
    missing_data <- data.frame(Date = missing_dates,
                               par1 = rep(NA, length(missing_dates)),
                               par2 = rep(NA, length(missing_dates)),
                               par3 = rep(NA, length(missing_dates)))
    
    data <- merge(new_data, missing_data, all = TRUE)
    
    # Sort the data by Date
    data <- data[order(data$Date), ]
    dt1 <- data[, 1:4]
    return(data[, 1:4])
  }   
    if (!is.null(input$simul$datapath)) {
      data_simul <- read.table(input$simul$datapath, header = FALSE)
      df_simul <- fill_missing_dates(data_simul)
      output$simulout <- renderTable(df_simul)
    }
  })
}

# Run the app
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

When I run the fill_missing_dates function alone with the provided data, it gives the expected output with correct date formats, as shown below:

```
       Date RR Tmax Tmin
2023-01-01  0   40   42
2023-01-02  0   40   25
2023-01-03  2   56   23
2023-01-04 NA   NA   NA
2023-01-05 NA   NA   NA
2023-01-06  5   65   65
2023-01-07  1    2    5
2023-01-08 NA   NA   NA
2023-01-09 NA   NA   NA
2023-01-10  5    6    2
```

However, when I use the same function within the Shiny app to process the "simul" file, it gives unexpected output in the "simulout" table, with dates shown as numeric values like "19358.00" instead of the expected date format:

```
Date    RR  Tmax    Tmin
19358.00    0   40  42
19359.00    0   40  25
19360.00    2   56  23
19361.00    NA  NA  NA
19362.00    NA  NA  NA
19363.00    5   65  65
19364.00    1   2   5
19365.00    NA  NA  NA
19366.00    NA  NA  NA
19367.00    5   6   2
```

I would appreciate any insights on why the Shiny app is displaying the "simulout" table with incorrect date formats, and any suggestions on how to fix this issue. Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`renderTable` does not behave very well with dates. If you want to stick with it, you can get a correct formatting by defining it before calling `renderTable`:

```
df_simul$Date <- format(df_simul$Date,'%Y-%m-%d')
output$simulout <- renderTable(df_simul)
```

An alternative would be to use `DT::renderDataTable()` and `DT::dataTableOutput()`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`d` being your initial data, you could try if this "tricks" `renderTable`:

```
d <- structure(list(y = c(2023L, 2023L, 2023L, 2023L, 2023L, 2023L
), m = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), d = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 6L, 7L, 10L
), p1 = c(0L, 0L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 5L), p2 = c(40L, 40L, 56L, 65L, 
2L, 6L), p3 = c(42L, 25L, 23L, 65L, 5L, 2L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
6L))
```

you can conveniently gather the year, month and day column into a date:

```
library(lubridate)

d <- d |> mutate(the_date = ymd(paste(y, m, d, sep = '/')))

## > d
##      y m  d p1 p2 p3   the_date
## 1 2023 1  1  0 40 42 2023-01-01
## 2 2023 1  2  0 40 25 2023-01-02
```

... then generate a separate dataframe containing a column of daily dates spanning your initial data's duration, join, and arrange by date:

```
library(dplyr)

d %>%
  right_join(
    data.frame(the_date = seq(from = min(.$the_date), to = max(.$the_date), by = 1))
  ) |>
  arrange(the_date)
```

output:

```
      y  m  d p1 p2 p3   the_date
1  2023  1  1  0 40 42 2023-01-01
2  2023  1  2  0 40 25 2023-01-02
3  2023  1  3  2 56 23 2023-01-03
4    NA NA NA NA NA NA 2023-01-04
5    NA NA NA NA NA NA 2023-01-05
6  2023  1  6  5 65 65 2023-01-06
7  2023  1  7  1  2  5 2023-01-07
8    NA NA NA NA NA NA 2023-01-08
9    NA NA NA NA NA NA 2023-01-09
10 2023  1 10  5  6  2 2023-01-10
```